# Super pom configuration for Mule project

Tags: build, mule, pom.xml, mule-studio, parent-pom

I am new to this mule and maven projects as well . Currently , I am using individual pom files for all the mule projects separately. Is there any way we can use super pom file to make the build simpler and refer all the child project from the parent pom .

Let me know if there is any documentation on how to execute build through parent pom .

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can have individual POM per application and overall you can define your parent POM as below

Parent POM - Under Modules define your apps

```
<project>
 <modelVersion>1.0</modelVersion>
 <groupId>groupID</groupId>
 <artifactId>Test1</artifactId>
 <version> 1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <modules>
    <module>../app1</module>
    <module>../app2</module>
    .....
  </modules>

 </project>
```

In  all the Child POM, you have to inherits the `<parent>` POM details so that you dont want to mentions the dependencies again.

```
 <project>
   <parent>
    <groupId>groupID</groupId>
    <artifactId>Test1</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>
   <modelVersion>1.0</modelVersion>
   <artifactId>Test2</artifactId>
</project>
```

More details

http://www.concretepage.com/build-tools/maven/parent-pom-child-pom-example

https://www.igorkromin.net/index.php/2015/11/08/getting-around-mavens-parent-child-project-version-dependency-issue/

Answer (score 0):

You could define a parent project that contains all the configuration of your mule project, like having the proper configuration and dependencies. And from your mule project(child), you could reference the parent pom.

```
<parent>
    <groupId>com.alexfrndz.parent</groupId>
    <artifactId>mule-parent-pom</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.0</version>
</parent>
```